# display grid with minmax and centering elements

Tags: html, css, css-grid

in a scenario like below how to place elements in the center of `wrap`
margins around elements can be elastic, but min 14px

```css
.wrap{
  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(90px, 100px));
    grid-column-gap:14px;
    grid-row-gap:14px;
    width:calc(100% - 30px);
    margin:0 auto;
    background:silver;
}
.el{
height:20px;
background:orange
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
<div class='el'></div>
<div class='el'></div>
<div class='el'></div>
<div class='el'></div>
<div class='el'></div>
<div class='el'></div>
<div class='el'></div>
<div class='el'></div>
<div class='el'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `justify-content: center;` into `.wrap`